# SQLAlchemy error on replacing child in an one-to-one relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I want to have a one-to-one relationship between a user and their last message. I expect that when I update their last message, the previous last message will get deleted from the database. Below is the minimal reproducible example

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, relationship, Mapped, DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class UserEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    last_message: Mapped["MessageEntity"] = relationship("MessageEntity", uselist=False)

class MessageEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "message"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    content: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    from_user_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    from_user: Mapped["UserEntity"] = relationship("UserEntity", back_populates="last_message", foreign_keys=[from_user_id])


DEFAULT_SQL_URL = "sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:"


engine = create_engine(DEFAULT_SQL_URL, echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

with Session(engine) as session:
    user1 = UserEntity(id="1")
    user2 = UserEntity(id="2")
    user1.last_message = MessageEntity(id="1", content="hello", from_user_id="1")
    session.add(user1)
    session.add(user2)
    session.commit()
    user1.last_message = MessageEntity(id="2", content="hello", from_user_id="1")
    session.add(user1)
    session.commit()
```

This fails with an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: message.from_user_id
[SQL: UPDATE message SET from_user_id=? WHERE message.id = ?]
[parameters: (None, '1')]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)
```

I'm unsure how `from_user_id` is not found, when I provide it explicitly within `MessageEntity` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, relationship, Mapped, DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

class UserEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    last_message: Mapped["MessageEntity"] = relationship("MessageEntity", uselist=False)

class MessageEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "message"

    content: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    from_user_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    from_user: Mapped["UserEntity"] = relationship("UserEntity", back_populates="last_message", foreign_keys=[from_user_id])


DEFAULT_SQL_URL = "sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:"


engine = create_engine(DEFAULT_SQL_URL, echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


with Session(engine) as session:
    user1 = UserEntity(id="1")
    user2 = UserEntity(id="2")
    session.add(user1)
    session.add(user2)
    session.commit()
    user1.last_message = MessageEntity(id="1", content="hello", from_user_id="1")
    user1.last_message = MessageEntity(id="2", content="hello", from_user_id="1")
    session.add(user1)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: The problem I have is that one `last_message` is committed into the database, and then has to be removed. In your script, the first `last_message` is not stored in the database, as it's replaced with the second `last_message` before the session commit.

Comment: It seems that message_entity was removed by rollback. You must run session.commit to make sure there is a user in database, then commit a message_entity with that one.

Comment: If I commit only the second/updated message entity, my script goes through, but it doesn't delete the previous message, so now the relationship is not one-to-one.

Comment: If I commit users to the database, beforehand, the error stays the same.

Comment: May this help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sqlalchemy-bulk-insert-with-one-to-one-relation/